# Symfony problem with autowire on server (Local works correcty)

Tags: symfony, autowired, symfony6

I have problem with autowire on my server. Symfony show me this:

```
Cannot autowire argument $authenticationUtils of "App\Controller\LoginController::index()": it references class "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils" but no such service exists.
```

My composer.json with all options:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=8.0.2",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/asset": "6.0.*",
    "symfony/console": "6.0.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "6.0.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^2",
    "symfony/form": "*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.0.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "6.0.*",
    "symfony/runtime": "6.0.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "6.0.*",
    "symfony/serializer": "6.0.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.0.*",
    "symfony/validator": "6.0.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "6.0.*",
    "twig/extra-bundle": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/stopwatch": "6.0.*",
    "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.0.*"
},
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
        "symfony/flex": true,
        "symfony/runtime": true
    },
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

In vendor have this folders:
[vendor/symfony](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIZr5.png)

And yes. File in /vendor/symfony/security-http/Authentication/AuthenticationUtils.php exist

I spent several hours looking for an answer, but all I found was that I didn't install the packages (which is not true)

Comment: Images are strongly discouraged.  Take a moment and learn how to format code in your question (hint use triple back-ticks) and post the relevant portion of your error message and maybe your services.yaml file.  No need to post composer.json and bundles.php unless you did something unusual when creating your app.

Comment: Unless you are limited to PHP 8.0 then there is no real reason to use 6.0.  I'd suggest starting over with a fresh project using the latest Symfony version (6.2 as of this writing, add a single controller using `bin/console make:controller` and then deploying.  I'm guessing you have some kind of issue on your server.  Once you have that working then use `make:user` `make:auth` and deploy again.

Comment: Did you restart phpfpm service on server after clearing cache / dependancy update ?

Comment: @ThomasL yes, but still not work

Comment: @Cerad Unfortunately, I'm addicted to PHP 8.0 and I don't think I can change it :/

Comment: @JerzyStępień Sorry to hear that.  6.1+ requires PHP 8.1+ so you have no upgrade path and 6.0 is no longer supported (bug fixes and what not).  You would probably be better off using 5.4 which has long term support.  Regardless, consider starting over and deploying a minimum application just to sort out your server problems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like path is wrong.
Are you using this namespace?

`namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication;`

Please verify this file exist in your vendor folder.

`/vendor/symfony/security-http/Authentication/AuthenticationUtils.php`

Comment: Yes. All required files exist in vendor. Symfony works fine on my machine (I'm using xampp). The problem only occurs on the server :/

Comment: Can you try with `composer install` again and then `php bin/console cache:clear` ?

Comment: Yeah... 3 times